# Python openCV Normalize with Zero Mean and unit variance

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to normalize an array of grayscale images with Zero Mean and unit variance with the cv2.normalize function as follows

```
out_image = np.zeros((32,32),dtype=np.float32)
out_array = np.zeros((len(X),32,32), dtype=np.uint8)        
for imageindex in range(0,len(X)): 
    img = X[imageindex].squeeze()
    if proctype == 'MeanSubtraction':
        out_image = img.astype(np.float32) - np.mean(img.astype(np.float32))
    elif proctype == 'Normalization':
        out_image = cv2.normalize(img.astype(np.float32), out_image, alpha=-0.5, beta=0.5,\
                                             norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_32F)
    elif proctype == 'HistEqualization':
        out_image = cv2.equalizeHist(img)

    elif proctype == 'CLAHE':
        clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(tileGridSize=(6,6),clipLimit = 20.0)
        out_image = clahe.apply(img)

    out_array[imageindex] = out_image.astype(np.uint8)

return out_array
```

However, if I use 0 and 1 (or 0 and 255) for the parameters alpha and beta for the normalize function, it works. But if I use -0.5 and +0.5, it returns me an empty image (all zeros)

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `out_array` is `np.uint8`, and so cannot represent floating point values accurately. Thus, when you cast `out_image`, which contains floating point values in the range `[-0.5, 0.5]`, to `np.uint8` with `out_image.astype(np.uint8)`, all those values are truncated to zero.  Consider this example:

```
# generate random numbers in the range [-0.5, 0.5]
x_float32 = (np.random.random((32, 32)) - 0.5).astype(np.float32)
print x_float32.min(), x_float32.max()  # prints -0.49861032, 0.4998906
x_uint8 = x_float32.astype(np.uint8)
print x_uint8.min(), x_uint8.max()      # prints 0, 0
```

If you want to store floating point values in `out_array`, you first need to change its `dtype` to `np.float32`.  Alternatively, you could renormalize the values in the range `[-0.5, 0.5]` to be unsigned integers in the range `[0, 255]`.

Comment: Yes. I changed the dtype of  out_array to np.float32 and now it works.. Thanks